# iOS How to create config file per target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I have been working on my first iOS app. I have completed all of its requirements. Now its time to distribute. But before distribution I want to manage things well.

I searched for it and got "Target" as what I wanted. now just suppose the following requirement:

> I have Client 1 and Client 2, and they both have different web addresses and Images and App Master password.

Now the 1 thing is to change them manually before making the build. But I wanted more proper way. So I thought of creating a Config file per target per client. but I am not getting it done.

Because after adding "Config" file for client 1 I am unable to create the 2nd "Config" file for Target 2 which indicates the client 2.

Please help me I am confused. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have different targets, you also have different property list attached to it. This allows you to customise some elements of your configuration for a specific target.

In this example, I duplicated my target and have now two targets, two schemes and two `.plist` files. I can customise one `.plist` without affecting the other target.

[image]

Another way to solve this problem is to create two configuration files in Swift. For instance, you can create a `AppConfig` struct foreach app configuration and attach it to one target at a time. It could be under `AppConfig.swift` and `AppConfigDemo.swift`, both with following code but different url in it.

```
struct AppConfig {
    let urlString = "https://myclienturl.com"
}
```

The key is to include each file into the right target. Here, this `AppConfig.swift` is available with `Test` target. It won't be accessible in `TestDemo` target. You can do the same foreach one of your client.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they have different names, Info.plist and Client2-Info.plist (for example).

and you can set targets config file in its build settings. just search for Info.plist and set the relative path to the configuration you need.
[image]

Comment: did not get your answer. Please describe it breifly